# Can Marketing Cloud Connector User be an API user instead of System Admin?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

1. Can MCC user in CRM be set as anything other than System Admin?
2. Is it possible to tailor the MCC user permissions to restrict Marketing Cloud from accessing specific Objects and/or fields?

e.g.1
we want to give Marketing Cloud access to Accounts but not to Leads

e.g.2 
we want to give Marketing Cloud access to a custom object but read only

e.g.2
we want to give Marketing Cloud access to a custom object with read only permission on 3 fields and write to 5 fields

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no official guidance on this, so this list comes with no guarantees. However it is the closest I got to enabling MCC without forcing an admin role on connector user in SC.

While this solution requires the least effort to implement, since it’s not officially supported by MC Connect product, and it's implemented upon your responsibility, there’s a risk that it might stop working in future releases, preventing new Journeys from activation (running Journeys won’t be affected). Therefore, monitoring and testing of new MC Connect and Core Platform releases is required.

- Author Apex

  - Modify Metadata Through Metadata API Functions
- Manage CRM Content

  - Manage Translation
  - View Setup and Configuration
  - Manage Custom Permissions
  - View Roles and Role Hierarchy
  - Customize Application
- Manage Sandboxes

  - Run Flows
  - Manage Flow
- Flow User on each Integration User record

This set of permissions assigned to Integration User record would allow to activate MC Journeys that use Salesforce Data Entry Source while respecting the sharing rules configured in Core CRM, so that we don’t get any duplicated data syncing to each Business Unit.
Journey Builder Entry Source filters by Market field are still required to prevent communications to wrong contacts.

Above permissions are in addition to standard MCC permissions: ConnectedApp, Marketing Cloud for AppExchange User/Admin

Comment: Thanks Lukas, this is great. When you say no guarantees, did you notice any unstable behavior e.g. the connector dropping etc.?

Comment: @SDE_Moustache No issues spotted so far. But that doesn’t mean I have covered all the potential cases.

Comment: hi team, have you noticed anything popping up in the past year that would need to be added to the above list?