# Restrict Contact Records in SFMC via the Connector

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforce-connect

We are using the Salesforce Marketing Cloud Connector. Is it possible to restrict the Contacts surfaced from SFDC into SFMC based on the Tracking User or will ALL Contacts which reside in SFDC be surfaced in SFMC? I realize there's the option to add limited filtering on the actual synchronized object, eg: only email or based on a certain field etc. My interest, however, is in knowing whether it's possible to use the Tracking User's Profile, or some visibility option, to restrict the Contacts surfaced in SFMC.

Thanks!

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, this functionality does not exist within the Connector. You will be limited to using the filtering that you've mentioned above in order to limit the records that you are synchronizing from the selected objects. You could add a boolean field on the object records that identifies those that you'd want to sync, but this is a fairly undesirable workaround.

Answer (score 0):

What ever records the api system user has access to within SFDC would be eligible to be synced over. This is different than any additional filtering done during the setup process

Comment: Doesn't the API user on the SFDC side have to be a system administrator, or at least have a permission level commensurate with that? You'd have to have an org-wide change to disable sys admin access to view all data/records in order to allow this user to selectively view data.

Comment: That is the recommendation during the setup process, but you are not locked into it. You would simply have to ensure the correct permissions were granted to account for every process you were using (ie JB entry events using Apex/process builder/flows )

Comment: @JasonHanshaw - you can use this list for reference: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/293410/can-marketing-cloud-connector-user-be-an-api-user-instead-of-system-admin/293497#293497

Comment: Gotcha, I see that view all data is on that list so I'm assuming that this can't be circumvented?

Comment: Thanks for sharing insights! Our use case is to restrict Contact records surfaced in SFMC to specific regions and omit other regions from surfacing in SFMC. For example, surface US Contacts and omit Canadian Contacts. Has any one else managed to achieve this use case? Thanks

Comment: I have a similar use case, and was wondering if Sharing Settings/Rules (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_data_access.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null) could be used with a “custom” sys admin profile?

Comment: @zuzannamj The main question is whether "View All Data" is a required permission for the SF user you are using with the Connector. If this is enabled, then that user can view all records from all objects irregardless of any sharing settings or permissions you have set.